# Label an WMS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, labeling

I have a WMS layer that shows geological layers. When I click the different areas with the info tool from the toolbar, I can see all additional data (see right side of image).

Yet, I don't see any option for placing a label on this layer.

What do I need to do? I'd like to label the different areas with the content of that "FeatureInfoCollection" on the right.

[image: Geological layers]

Comment: I don't think you can label the WMS layer itself in QGIS.  If the WMS is yours you can enable labelling, otherwise perhaps you can create a second layer that has the same extent as the WMS layer, and label that.

Comment: You could also create a custom SLD and send that with your GetMap request.

Answer (score 2):

A WMS does not offer that kind of feature. The information you get by clicking is actually requested from the WMS when you click, just for that single point, with a GetFeatureInfo request.

Comment: Is there a plugin which fires that request for each layer?

Comment: No and this is not a layer-centric thing but as I said, just for a single point for each request. Every GetFeatureInfo request only yields information for a single coordinate.